# Get key level depth in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php

I'm trying to search through a multi-dimensional array to return the depth/value and whether it exists, but i'm having a little bit of trouble..

Theres a number of depths/dimensions of my array.. I'm storing current multi-dimensional arrays within others.. Here is an example:

```
array(
        "UserInformation" => array(
                array ( 
                 "Username" => "Test_User",
                 "Warnings" => 0,
                 "Post_ID" => array (7726,2254)                      
                ),
                array (
                "Username" => "Another",
                "Warnings" => 2,
                "WarningID" => array(8874,1125),
                "Post_ID" => array (7726,2254)
                 ),
        ),
        "Mani" => 0,
        "Aut" => 1,
        "Wn" => 0,
        "RTV"=> array(
            "RunTime"=> "kk",
            "Run_2" => "e",
            "Perm"=>"p",
            "DEp"=>"d")
    );
```

Now, How would I go about searching the entire array index without nested `for` or `foreach` loops?

I've tried performing an `array_search` but this returns no aval as it only searches through the first dimension, and not in more depth?

Comment: @zerkms Quite shamefully, I have never fully understood the concept/practice of having a sucessful function to do just this

Comment: Like @zerkms said, recursion. Or you could use a freely available iterator https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden

Comment: @Daryl Gill: just try and we'll help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this one.

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) { 
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) { 
        $current_key=$key; 
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value))) { 
            return $current_key; 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Here OR is for checking whether the needle value is same with the value you are searching. If it is true it will directly return the key and if it is not true it will first check the value is an array then call the same function recursively by changing its input with new nested array. So like this way it will iterate recursively end level of the array to find the value.

Comment: If i have to explain all the statement in a function then other question will miss by me :). Thanks @BenHarold

Comment: Actually yeah. I jist About understand the reasons to use and, or within this function. There will be other users who might not, an explanation would be beneficial

Comment: I have answered this question in hurry but my concern to to show the way to get your result. Thats why I show you a recursive call to search an array. Anyways if its helps you tat would enough for me.

Comment: @AmarBanerjee Which is something which i'm greatful for. I will put it into practice and let you know the results in a little while. But i'm concerned for the other users who navigate to this question, if any. There will be no point for a user who doesn't understand the concept and practice of recursion and the functions used. Stack Overflow is an archival multi-purpose website which gives information/snippets for users who are not as informed into a programming language.

Comment: Just tested it out.. It returns the dimension of the first key set, eg: `echo recursive_array_search("Another",$Test);` returns: "UserInformation" not: "UserInformation,2". But thanks for the base point, I will work with this function to get the return that i'm expecting

Answer (score 0):

Amar's modified code which worked for me:

```
/*
 * recusrive array search 
 * @param array $array
 * @param string $needle
 * @return string|int:
 */

public function recursiveFind(array $array, $needle)
{
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

    foreach ($iterator as $key => $item) {
        $current_key = $key;
        if (is_array($item) && $key === $needle) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
}
```

in this code case I needed ID (int) or keep looking in array (string) until I reach the one